# How to make distorted grid lettering?

Tags: modeling, texturing, workflow, text-object

How can I make an effect like the picture below?

[image: desired output]

Comment: yes it is. I'd recommend making your text a displacement map, and displacing a plane with a grid material on one axis. I can write up an answer later

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used any 3d software before so yes, a short tutorial would be very welcome, or if you could point out relevant tutorial pages or videos that would be also great and possibly less time consuming for you. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot]

Take a plane; scale, subdivide, rotate, unwrap it; Add a Wireframe modifier and a Displacement modifier. Use your text as hieght texture. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

I have made a tutorial especially for you, but it is too long for an animated gif, so here is a YT link:
https://youtu.be/7AMEFoZOb7s

[image]